# How to write bigquery SQL to undersample rows for majority class while keeping all samples of minority class?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch data for a binary classification problem. The dataset is heavily imbalanced. I can download the data and do the undersampling of majority class but I want to know how can I directly do it using BigQuery SQL?

In other words, I want to select all samples where target column is `1` and ignore significant amount of data if target column is `0`.

Sample Dataset

```
id   feat_1    feat_2    target
1     x_1        y_1       0
2     x_2        y_4       1
3     x_3        y_1       0
4     x_1        y_1       1
5     x_2        y_4       0
6     x_2        y_1       0
.
.
.
```

Can I somehow select random samples of target `0` such that none of feat_2 values are completely lost in random sampling?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following command to get some random values from table

```
SELECT * FROM table where rand() < Sample_no/Total_no and  target=0
```

Where `Sample_no`  is no of sample records you need as output and `Total_no`  is total no of records on table.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull one `0` row per `feat_2`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by feat_2, target order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where target = 1 or seqnum = 1;
```

The above returns all `1`s and then one `0` row per `feat_2`.

If you want one row per `feat_2`, biased toward the `1`s, then you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by feat_2 order by target desc, rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```